# Firebase Realtime Database - Rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

my Firebase RTD is structured as follows:

```
messages :{
   userId1: {
               userId2: {sentFrom: userId1, messageText: 'hello user 2 from user 1'}
            },
   userId2: {
               userId1: {sentFrom: userId1, messageText: 'hello user 2 from user 1'}
            },
}
```

I want user1 to be able to write to DB if path is `message/userId1`.....but I also want user1 to be able to write if path is `message/anyOtherUserId/userId1`

The json I am using in rules is as per below....and when I hit path `message/userId1` its a success...but when I hit `message/anyOtherUserId/userId1` it returns "Simulated set denied"

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
        "$userId": {
          ".write": "$userId === auth.uid ? true : (root.child($userId).val()===auth.uid ? true : false)",
        }, 
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the simulator settings as you get the error. Make sure it shows the path and value you write, settings you use, and the rule that is failing. Also: show the actual JSON, and not "pseudo-code". You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to further cascade the rules. Try this in your simulation:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "messages":{
          "$userId":{
            ".write": "$userId === auth.uid",
            "$userIdChild": {
              ".write": "$userIdChild === auth.uid"
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

*I hope this helps!!*